# REST API SearchCriteria for Quantity

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I try to get all active products with a quantity less then 5. I getall active products via

```
V1/products/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

But how do I add a filter to a quantity <5 ? I added this criteria, but it didnt work:

```
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=extension_attributes[stock_item[qty]]&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=5&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=lt
```

Can somebody explan how to create a searchCriteria for nested fields? Because I think this seems to be the problem here...

Comment: what magento version are you suing? are you using multisource-inventory?

Comment: magento v2.2.3, and no multisource-inventory

Comment: by taking a quick look at your query, I noticed a typo: `&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=extension_attributes[stock_item][qty]&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=5&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=lt` it has to be [stock_item][qty] and not [stock_item[qty]]. i have not tested this

Comment: that's wring because qty is nested in "stock_item" which is nested in "extension_attributes"

Comment: did you finally find a way through this ?

Answer (score 0):

I researched the documentation as of 2.4 there is no way to filter products based on quantity, so the only option left is to extend the rest api with some custom module.